# Disable the save warning on TinyMCE editors

Tags: joomla-4.x, editor, tinymce

I've programmed a modal with a TinyMCE editor inside, where it's value is saved via ajax, but when leaving the page there's still the warning `Changes you made may not be saved.`

Is there a function or some sort of flag I can configure to avoid the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is caused by a bound `onbeforeunload` event that is being added via the autosave plugin. To completely disable it;

```
var editor = window.Joomla.editors.instances['{editor}'];
editor.instance.plugins.autosave = {};
```

Replace `{editor}` with the id of the editor.

Addendum (2022-09-15):
This code now throws an error during the `onbeforeunload` event. I've found a fix already:

```
var editor = window.Joomla.editors.instances['{editor}'];
editor.instance.plugins.autosave = {storeDraft:function(){editor.instance.setDirty(false)}};
```